# What is wrong with this set of routers?

Tags: routing, packet-tracer

[image]

What is wrong with this network, why am I unable to connect to the internet from the network 172.16.1.0 here?

I've done all the routing setup using GUI (that should not cause the problem, though). Any help appreciated!

Comment: Hello cdummie and welcome to NE ... it's much better to copy/paste the output of commands (eg `show ip route`) rather than images ... means they get indexed and so on.  In your question, what are the routes on R3?  It's also most helpful if you copy/paste the (no passwords please!) configurations.

Comment: R2's default route points back to R1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R2's default route points back to R1. Instead it needs to point to R3 via Serial0/0/1.

Comment: @Ron Trunk Seriously? We typed the exact same sentence at the exact same time. Spooky... =8^O

Comment: Quantum network effects :)

Comment: Ok, thanks both of you guys! I'll try to fix it.